# Javascript SetInterval executing script 13 time every interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So here is my script, I don't understand at all what is happening.

```
var reloadTableInterval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log('ABC');
}, 120000);
```

When I do this, I notice that it writes 13 time the "ABC" in my console everytime the interval is completed. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong?

Note that this function is part of a AngularJS(1.3) controller.

```
app.controller('unitCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $compile){
    //...
}]);
```

Also, I have 7 directive that uses my Controller, they are all built this way but with different name:

```
app.directive('clientInfoModal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/reservations/template/ClientInfoModal.html',
        controller: 'unitCtrl'
    };
});
```

And they are loaded at the bottom of my HTML document (it's a single page small application)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/unitController.js"></script>
<script src="js/directive/saleModal.js"></script>
<script src="js/directive/reservationModal.js"></script>
<script src="js/directive/clientInfoModal.js"></script>
<script src="js/directive/unitsTable.js"></script>
<script src="js/directive/waitingListModal.js"></script>
<script src="js/directive/oneUnitWaitingListModal.js"></script>
<script src="js/directive/newNoteModal.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems like you load your controller 13 times. Impossible to answer without seeing more context

Comment: Does every directive that uses this controller that is loaded at the bottom of my HTML document load another instance of my controller?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you polling for data? Since reloadTableInterval sounds peculiar.

Comment: @Shilly I was using AJAX and was curious if it was the problem, but them switched it for a console log and the same problem happens

Comment: Replace your `console.log...` with `console.log(new Error().stack)` and then see if all 13 are identical or if something else is going on

Comment: @baao the rest of the code is not related, but I'll add something in case

Comment: @GeorgeJempty they are all running same controller, same line.

Comment: Yes, every time the directive is used it initializes a new copy of the controller. If you use it 13 times the controller function is called 13 times.

Comment: Do you only want that line to run once across all controllers? What are you trying to accomplish @YannChabot?

Comment: @Treeless yes I believe I was seeing it the wrong way, I think I found the way, I'll check if the variable that defines the interval is set and if its not then I'll set the interval, I tought that the controller was only defined once and that then the directive was just using the information from my controller, I didn't tought they were extending my controller creating another instance of it another time, it's my bad really

Comment: @YannChabot No worries glad you sorted it out! It sorta sounds like what you need is some sort of service that handles that functionality. The variable within the controller will not be the same accross all the controller instances. Let me know if you want an example and I'll create an answer.

Comment: @Treeless yes please, I am fairly new to AngularJS (my 2nd project using it) and I must admit I didn't got around services so much, I'd love an example if possible !

Comment: @YannChabot Going to keep adding to my answer. But let me know if it's what your looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Fixed answer based on OP's question comment thread

```
app.service('intervalCheckService', ['$interval', function($interval) {
  return {
    intervalRun: false,
    setInterval: function() {
      if (!intervalRun) {
        this.intervalRun = true;
        var reloadTableInterval = $interval(function() {
          console.log('ABC');
        }, 120000);
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

Include that service in your app as a dependency. Then inject it into your controller.

```
app.controller('unitCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'intervalCheckService', function($scope, $http, $compile, intervalCheckService) {
  intervalCheckService.setInterval();
  //...
}]);
```

The angular docs has a great example of a service as well if you need more examples: [See Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: `$interval` doesn't prevent the interval from being started multiple times.

Comment: @JJJ yeah it behave the same

Comment: Changed my answer to work with the new info OP gave in his comments under his question. See here @YannChabot